# Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied generate:bundle

Tags: php, symfony, file-permissions

I am trying to generate a bundle from a controller. But I am having permission denied error. And I can't figure out why.

Here is my controller code:

```
    $app = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($this->get("kernel"));
    $app->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput(array(
        "command"=>"generate:bundle",
        "--namespace"=>"testNewAnBundle",
        "-n"=>""
    ));

    $out = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput();

    $app->run($input, $out);
    return new Response("<body>".$out->fetch()."</body>");
```

The output is:

```
Bundle generation > Generating a sample bundle skeleton into app/../src/testNewAnBundle [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException] Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied generate:bundle [--namespace NAMESPACE] [--dir DIR] [--bundle-name BUNDLE-NAME] [--format FORMAT] [--shared] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-s|--shell] [--process-isolation] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]
```

This create the folder testNewAnBundle/ in src/ and the folder testNewAnBundle/ has testNewAnBundle.php and Controller/DefaultController.php files generated.

The path testNewAnBundle/* permision is:

```
drwxrwxrwx+ www-data www-data testNewAnBundle
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 www-data www-data 4096 mai   14 16:13 Controller
-rw-rw-rw-  1 www-data www-data  125 mai   14 16:13 testNewAnBundle.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have to use ACL command line in user mode (not root)

HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`

sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var

sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var

Comment: For information: the code `ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1` returns something like `www-data Apache`. Note the space. There is no `\ `. So `cut -d\  -f1` delimiter `\ ` do not work.